# Reverse engineering the Hill Sphere?

Tags: planets, space, moons, orbital-mechanics, astronomy

I'm wondering if anyone has run into the issue of "I know the general idea of how big my moon is but not the parent planet" and how to sort of reverse engineer finding out the mass/radius of the planet to then find out its Hill sphere?

Comment: Mass is inconsequential to orbital dynamics. A spacecraft and a spaceman will orbit at the same speed. The first thing you need to know is the orbital period of your moon, after which orbital distance will be a function of the mass of the primary object. Then you decide how far away you want it to be so that it covers the right amount of the sky, based on its mass and density. This is really a physics question. Have you tried https://physics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I can't think of why this isn't possible - but it does require you to arbitrarily declare some variables to find the planetary mass. Use the [Hill radius equation](http://astro.vaporia.com/start/hillradius.html) only work backwards to planetary mass rather than forward to the radius. However, I agree with @RobertRapplean, this Q would likely be well received and better answered either at [physics.se] or [astronomy.se].

Answer (score 2):

## Choose Exactly one

Wikipedia says the hill sphere radius is given by

$$H = r\sqrt[3]{\frac{m}{3M}}$$

for $r$ the orbital radius, $m$ the (known) mass of the moon and $M$ the mass of the planet.

This means you can choose the radius and mass of the planet and use the above to compute the Hill sphere.

Alternately you can choose the Hill sphere radius and plug into

$$M =\frac{m}{3} \frac{r^3}{H^3}$$

to get the mass that gives that Hill sphere.

I guess you get to choose the radius too. So it's really more a case of

## choose exactly two.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the mass of the moon there is still the difficulty of having two variables, The Hill sphere radius and the mass of the planet. So there will be multiple solutions and the best you can hope for is a ratio.

One potential way of exploring these solutions is to put the Hill sphere formula with the known mass of the moon into a spreadsheet and try playing with different planetary masses to see what Hill radius you get until you find one that is suitable.

The formula for calculating a hill sphere can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere
Results can be verified here:
https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/KurtHeckman/Hill+Sphere+Radius

Another way around this is to continue to explore your story and see if you can discover any other restricting factors such as month length etc. This might then help you zero in on the correct value for the Hill radius.